# jQuery ajax call doesn't call my php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, browser-cache, persona

I'm implementing Mozilla's persona authentication (ie browserid).
So, I have the following onLogin():

```
function onLogin(pAssertion) {
    var sPHPSessionID = $.cookies.get("PHPSESSID")+'';
    var sFoolCache = new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.random();
    $.ajax(
      {
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/webservice.php?id=personaauth&u=i',
        data: { assertion: pAssertion, PHPSESSID: sPHPSessionID, z: sFoolCache },
        success: function(res, status, xhr) { alert("do reload");  },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            navigator.id.logout(); 
            alert("Login failure: " + err); 
      }
  });
}
```

Where there's the "alert("do reload")" I normally have a window.location.reload() call.
The problem is that, nonetheless all my efforts to clear and not use the browser cache (Firefox), my /webservice.php page doesn't get called, at all. The ajax call immediately executes the "success" function (which keeps my window reloading in a dramatic loop, if I leave the "reload()" call in the code).
I need the PHP session id in my /webservice.php call, so I pass the PHPSESSIONID cookie to the page.

I cleared my firefox cache. I closed my browser, I added the 'sFoolCache' variable to the url (and not the post) but it didn't work either.
I'm lost.

Comment: My guess is that your webservice.php is not located in the top level directory. What response do you get if you enter http://<your_host>/webservice.php in your browser?

Comment: Also, `success`, `error` and such properties are depracated as of jQuery 1.8. Use `$.ajax().done(function(data) { /* ... */ })` instead. Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.

Comment: I knew my webservice.php url was good, should have told you that in my question, thanks Andy. @Michal: Pheew!, blabla.done(). And that did it. Awsome ! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's problem with passing URL, try passing the full URL:

```
function onLogin(pAssertion) {
    var sPHPSessionID = $.cookies.get("PHPSESSID")+'';
    var sFoolCache = new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.random();
    $.ajax(
        {
             cache: false,
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'FullURL and querystring',
             data: { assertion: pAssertion, PHPSESSID: sPHPSessionID, z: sFoolCache },
             success: function(res, status, xhr) { alert("do reload");  },
             error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                 navigator.id.logout(); 
                 alert("Login failure: " + err); 
             }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As it appeared to help in this case, I'm undeleting this answer**

Check here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Use this instead:

```
$.ajax(/* ... */)
.done(function(data) { /* ... */ })
.failure(function(data) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: That's it. Here's how I rewrote it to make it work: See next post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

So, Thanks to @Michal, here's how I rewrote it to make it work (btw, I had to answer myself, as my comment was otherwise too long):

```
function onLogin(pAssertion) {
  var sPHPSessionID = $.cookies.get("PHPSESSID")+'';
  var sFoolCache = new Date().getTime() + '' + Math.random();
  $.ajax(
    {
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/webservice.php?id=personaauth&u=i',
      data: { assertion: pAssertion, PHPSESSID: sPHPSessionID, z: sFoolCache }
    }).done(function(res, status, xhr) { 
        window.location.reload();
        }).fail( function(xhr, status, err) {
          navigator.id.logout(); 
          alert("Login failure: " + err); 
        });
}
```

Please vote for Michal's answer (up here), not this one ;-)
Thanks guys.